# Maintaining User Sessions in PHP with Security

Tags: php, session, cookies, sql-injection

I want to know how developers to maintain sessions between different php files professionally, as the user navigates through the website.

I have seen all tutorials, but I think they are not safe.

I have just made a login php file and created sessions associated with userid, username within the database and if remember me is checked, it will create a cookie.

```
$username = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['username']);
$password = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['password']);  
$rememberMe = (int)$_POST['rememberMe'];


$row = mysql_fetch_assoc(mysql_query("SELECT id,usr FROM members WHERE usr='{$username}' AND pass='".md5($password)."'"));

if($row['usr'])
{
  $_SESSION['usr']=$row['usr'];
  $_SESSION['id']=$row['id'];
  $_SESSION['rememberMe']=$_POST['rememberMe'];

  if($rememberMe=="on")
   setcookie('zsCookie',$username, time()+7200);


}
```

Now lets say, I make a profile php. How do I get the users session? I want to know the professional way how developers do this on sites like facebook. After getting this session, how may I use it to retrieve values from my database with full security.

Also is my authenticating code safe from sql injection?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You use `session_start()` and go on with your life.

Your particular query is safe, but realize that when you run a string through md5, any SQL escaping you did on the original string is destroyed - md5's output character set does not include sql metacharacters, so if a user's password DOES contain any of the metacharacters, you've now hashed not only their password, but any escape characters that were added in. You will have to do this escaping EVERYWHERE you do password operations, otherwise you'll end up with one spot where a particular user's PW won't work because they happen to have an SQL metachar in the pw.

Answer (score 1):

The way you usually do that is using SESSIONS.

You can do a:

```
session_start();
```

at the beginning of your script and then use:

```
$_SESSION['userid'] = $myuserid;
```

Then, when a page loads back, start_session() again and look into $_SESSION to see if your userid is there. If it is there, load the user data from the database using that user id.

For example:

```
'SELECT * FROM users_table WHERE id = '.$_SESSION['userid'];
```

Note that there many more considerations regarding security that you should implement, lookup the session section in php.net for more info:

http://www.php.net/sessions/

Good luck

Answer (score 1):

your query is safe from SQL-injection, though the mysql_real_escape_string call on the $_POST['password'] is unnecessary as when run through md5() the output will only contain alphanumeric characters and cannot contain SQL commands.

As for sessions, that is another matter. Many PHP developers make use of PHP's default sessions through use of functions like session_start() being called on each page that needs to support sessions, and storing information that needs to be on each page in the $_SESSION superglobal. Check out the PHP documentation for sessions over here: https://www.php.net/manual/en/book.session.php

With that being said, a custom session implementation can achieve greater security and efficiency, but that takes a good deal more work.